# moving a file in python using shutil

Tags: python, shutil

I know there have been some posts on how to move a file in python but I am a little confused. I am working on a program that has a file called test.txt

The file path is this: `C:\Users\user\Desktop\Project1\Project1` 
I want to move it to: `C:\Users\user\Documents\ProjectMoved` 
I tried different variations of what I have below

```
src="C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Project1\\Project1\\test.txt"
dst="C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\ProjectMoved"
shutil.move(src, dst)
```

I keep getting the error no such file in directory.

I was wondering if someone could help me out with the correct way to move the file.

Comment: Does `C:\Users\user\Documents\ProjectMoved` exist? You probably have to create it.

Comment: dst is not quoted correctly - too many leading "s.

Comment: @Rawing yes it does exist

Comment: are you trying to move the file test.txt to a directory or file called ProjectMoved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Might be worth checking the file exists and then trying to specify paths using `os.path.join`:

```
import shutil
import os
from os.path import join

src = join('/', 'Users', 'username', 'Desktop', 'a.pdf')
dst = join('/', 'Users', 'username', 'Documents', 'a.pdf')

shutil.move(src, dst)
```

You can first verify if the `src` actually exists:

```
os.path.exists(src)
>>> True
```

Comment: It does exists when I do it with the src=join

Comment: thank you it worked. Can you explain to me what join does? and why we needed the '/'

Comment: Also is there a way to search your whole computer for a specific file in python

Comment: `os.path.join` can create a full pathname from multiple components (among other things).  You might want to use it cause then you can specify path names across any type of operating system.  The 'slash' is the root directory (yes, it's an actual directory name).  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_directory

Comment: If you're starting in Python, be aware that the `join` function was imported from the `os.path` module.  So you could remove the line `from os.path import join` and then use `os.path.join` instead of `join` in the above script, but you'd be best to read about importing modules in Python elsewhere (it's really a separate question).  Searching for files using Python is a separate question - search SO for answers to this.

Comment: Thanks, you were really helpful. I wish I can give you more points

Comment: so I can do src = os.path.join('/'...) what would I import?

Comment: `src = os.path.join('/')` would make the variable `src` a pathname to the root directory.  It's probably not what you're after, the root directory is best left alone.  Pointing to the desktop or your own documents folder would probably be safer.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can also be solved this way if your trying to move multiple .txt files from Folder A to folder B. This principle can be applied to your problem since your moving .txt file.

```
import os
import shutil
os.chdir('C:\\') 

dir_src = ("C:\\Folder A\\")
dir_dst = ("C:\\Folder B\\")

for filename in os.listdir(dir_src):
    if filename.endswith('.txt'):
        shutil.move( dir_src + filename, dir_dst)
    print(filename)
```